# How to store saved checkbox value in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm studying Laravel and made contact form.

my Laravel Framework is 7.15.0

I wrote this code to saving form values useing old function.

```
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1[]" 
value="A" @if(is_array(old('q1')) && in_array("A", old('q1'))) checked @endif>
  <label class="form-check-label" >A</label>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q1[]" 
value="B"  @if(is_array(old('q1')) && in_array("B", old('q1'))) checked @endif>
  <label class="form-check-label" >B</label>
```

However after I wrote this I couldn't store data to my mysql.

Here is error message.

> ErrorException
> Array to string conversion

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:449

Seems like saving array data to my mysql is problem I guess.

Here is my controller code.

Could someone teach me how to write store data as not array please?

```
public function ContactUsForm(Request $request) {

    // Form validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',    
     ]);         
    Contact::create($request->all());       
    
    \Mail::send('mail', array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'q1_s' => $request->get('q1')
    ), function($message) use ($request){
        $message->from($request->email);
        $message->to('mail@myemailadress.com', 'you got mail ')->subject($request->get('you got mail'));
    });
```

Comment: Your name `name="q1[]" ` will make the $request to handle an array, just replace it by `name="q1" ` since you use radio button in your code

Comment: The checkbox is a array, so it contains multiple values. The solution of @VincentDecaux is a option but it will make you create a lot of names. You can just loop trough the array values.

Comment: @Vincent Decaux Thank you for helping me. I changed as q1 but when user refresh the page the q1 value will gone.

Comment: @Collin Thank you for answering me. I have little validation in this code. I need save checkbox value when user reload this page. if I do like name="q1[]" I can save the old data. I would like to store this data to my database.

Comment: What is the relation between the checkbox content and the contact.

Comment: Array to string `old('q1[0]')`

Comment: @Collin Checkbox are part of contact form. Contact form working fine. every text input and textare keep data using 'old' function except checkbox. I've been searching to keep checkbox data. but now I realized I can keep old data but I can't store those data to my database.

Comment: @Talha F. Thank you. Could you show me how to write code please?